# can't change different footnote/endnote font sizes in MS Word 2011

Tags: macos, fonts, formatting, microsoft-word-2011, footnote

I've already consulted all the instruction on how to change formatting of footnotes/endnotes in Microsoft Word 2011. The problem is the settings say I'm using the same size font, same font, all throughout my endnotes, but new notes APPEAR in a different size.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You're using a Mac? Are you using Word's default style set?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Mac.Default style? I think.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and putting a return before or after that footer content made the font size stick. hope that helps.